Как в libreoffice calc вставить пустую строку через каждые 10 строк
Как в libreoffice calc вставить пустую строку через каждые 10 строк
чтобы получалось так:

как проще это сделать. Строк очень много в программировании не силен.

например, сохранить в формате csv, вставить пустые строки (например, с помощью программы sed: sed '10~10G'), сохранить в любом нужном формате.

Вставлять только макросом, вставлять с конца
Sub InsertEmptyRows
   
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rowCount As Long
    
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oSheet = oDoc.CurrentController.ActiveSheet ' Получаем активный лист
    rowCount = 80 ' Последняя строка от которой делить по 10
    
    For i = rowCount To 1   Step -1
        If (i Mod 10) = 0 Then 
            oSheet.Rows.insertByIndex(i, 1) ' Вставляем пустую строку
            
        End If
    Next i

   
End Sub




Ого работает, спасибо большое. А что значит вставлять с конца?

Пустые строки вставляются с последней строки и как бы "уходят вниз", если вставлять с первой  строки, то пустые строки будут входить в "десятку" строк и на каждом шаге все будет съезжать.
